# Same line for path() and paragraph

Tags: twig, prettier

I would like to know if it's possible to force prettier to write my "path" in one line:

This is what I have:

```
<a href="{{ path('product_conf', { slug: product.slug }) }}">
```

But prettier write this element like this:

```
<a href="{{
    path(
        'product_conf',
        {
            slug: product.slug
        }
    )
    }}">
```

Same for my h3, p, etc :

```
<h3>
    Let's go!
</h3>
```

(I would like: `<h3> Let's go! </h3>`)

My prettierrc.json

```
{
    "singleQuote": true,
    "useTabs": true,
    "printWidth": 180,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "singleAttributePerLine": true,
    "plugins": [
        "./node_modules/prettier-plugin-twig-melody"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `"twigAlwaysBreakObjects": false` in your **.prettierrc.json.**